# How to find a tighter upper bound on the spectral radius of the given matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, upper-lower-bounds, spectral-radius

Given that the eigenvalues of this matrix are all real,
I need to find the spectral radius of this matrix

\begin{pmatrix} 2n-1&& n-1&& n\\ 1&& 2n-3&& 0\\
1&& 0&& 1\end{pmatrix}

I used the Gersgorin Disc Theorem which gives that that the eigenvalues of the above matrix can lie in the intervals $(0,4n-2),(0,2), (2n-4,2n-2)$. However, I want to find a tighter upper bound of the spectral radius.

1. Are there any other theorems which can give a tighter upper bound of the above matrix?
2. Is there any other procedure to find an upper bound of the spectral radius of this matrix?

If someone could help, I would be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Upper_bound). Maybe it will help

Comment: Are you looking for what happens at large $n$?

Comment: @Conifold; yes absolutely

Comment: This is $3\times3$ so you can write out the characteristic polynomial explicitly, and then estimate its largest root, e.g. by [Graeffe's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeffe%27s_method). See also [MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/q/72614/51484).

Comment: Here is another idea. Divide your matrix by $n$, the limit is upper triangular with $2,2,0$ on the diagonal, so the limit spectral radius is $2$. This gives $2n$ as the asymptotic radius for your matrix with large $n$.

Comment: @Conifold; I put $n=3$ above in the matrix. I found the spectral radius as $6.20$ which is greater than $3$ , so how can the spectral radius be $2n$?

Comment: @Math_Freak do you understand what "asymptotic" means in this context?

Comment: @Math_Freak you need to divide by $n=3$, so your spectral radius is not too far from Conifold's estimations.

Comment: Using the GDT on the columns instead gives you the smaller upper bound of $3n - 4$

Comment: $2n$ is only the leading term, and the asymptotics only holds for large $n$.

Comment: By the way: the usual phrase is "tighter" rather than "more tight"

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 2n-1&& n-1&& n\\ 1&& 2n-3&& 0\\
1&& 0&& 1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Let $D$ be the diagonal matrix
$$
D = \pmatrix{1\\&\sqrt{n}\\&&n},
$$
Consider the matrix $DAD^{-1}$, which is similar to $A$. We compute
$$
DAD^{-1} = \pmatrix{
2n-1&& \frac{n-1}{\sqrt{n}}&& 1\\ \sqrt{n}&& 2n-3&& 0\\
n&& 0&& 1
}.
$$
The upper bound from the GCT applied to this matrix is
$$
\max\{2n + \sqrt{n} - 1 - \frac 1{\sqrt n}, 
2n + \sqrt{n} , n+1\} = 2n + \sqrt{n}.
$$
More generally, you might find it useful to try this with different diagonal matrices $D$.

---

Another approach worth considering: we can write $A = Bn + C$, where
$$
B = \pmatrix{2&1&1\\0&2&0\\0&0&0}, \quad
C = \pmatrix{-1&-1&0\\1&-3&0\\1&0&1}.
$$
From there, the spectral radius is bounded above by 
$$
r(A) \leq \|A\| = \|Bn + C\| \leq \|Bn\| + \|C\| = n \|B\| + \|C\|,
$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is any choice of submultiplicative matrix norm.  For instance, taking $\|\cdot\|$ to be the spectral norm yields $\|B\| < 2.67$, $\|C\| < 3.25$, so that
$$
\|A\| \leq 2.67n + 3.25.
$$

---

On computing the best diagonal $D$:

Let $D$ be given by
$$
D = \pmatrix{1\\&\alpha\\&&\beta}.
$$
with $\alpha, \beta > 0$. We compute
$$
D^{-1}AD = 
\begin{pmatrix} 2n-1&& \alpha(n-1)&& \beta n\\ 
\alpha^{-1}&& 2n-3&& 0\\
\beta^{-1}&& 0&& 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
The resulting upper bounds on the spectral radius are the absolute row sums, namely
$$
2n - 1 + \alpha(n-1) + \beta n,\\
(2n - 3) + \alpha^{-1},\\
1 + \beta^{-1}.
$$
The best possible upper bound is the solution to the min-max problem
$$
\min_{\alpha,\beta \geq 0}
\max\{
2n - 1 + \alpha(n-1) + \beta n,
(2n - 3) + \alpha^{-1},
1 + \beta^{-1}
\}.
$$

Comment: By Conifolds observation, the tightest possible upper bound has the form $2n + o(n)$.  Happily, $2n + \sqrt{n}$ has this form (but probably isn't the tightest possible bound).

Comment: Does there exist any way to find the form $\circ  (n)$?

Comment: How to find the diagonal matrix which minimizes the bound?

Comment: $o(n)$ is "little-O" asymptotic notation, not a precise function of $n$. If you're looking for the tightest possible upper bound, then you might as well compute the eigenvalues as a function of $n$.

Comment: Finding the diagonal matrix that minimizes the resulting upper bound is straightforward but tedious

Comment: You could also find the spectral radius using the formula 
$$
\rho(A) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \|A^k\|^{1/k},
$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is any submultiplicative norm.  Notably, plugging in any particular $k$ will give you an upper bound

Comment: Sir, the diagonal matrix $D$ can have different entries , it can be $diag(1/n,1,1)$ or $diag(1/n,1/n^2,2)$ and many others. I dont understand how to find the diagonal matrix which can minimize the spectral radius

Comment: Will you please explain a little bit more

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what it is that you're looking for or why you're looking for it? At this rate, no matter which method I suggest you could ask for a slightly smaller upper bound.  Technically speaking, your original query has been answered.

Comment: "Finding the diagonal matrix that minimizes the resulting upper bound is straightforward but tedious" this is what you wrote

Comment: I dont understand how to find the diagonal matrix, I tried many but they are giving different bounds, what shall i do now?

Comment: Is my question clear? please let me know if its unclear

Comment: Your question is clear

Comment: Can you kindly help sir if its clear?

Comment: I mis-remembered, finding an optimal $D$ is not as easy as I thought.  However, it can be framed as an optimization problem, and I suspect that this problem can be solved with linear programming.  I have updated my answer to this effect.